# Hot to fix bag with focus on input in fixed container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a problem with scrolling body on iOS platform (iPhone test) when I make focused on input in fixed div.

```
html
body
 header
  -> logo
  -> menu
  -> buttons
  --> button--search
     ...
  -> search-module
  --> input#search

 search-result
  -> result-1 ... result-n

 ... 

/body
/html
```

header - fixed div

When I call function focus on input (#search) by button click (button--search) all is ok, but only on iOS (and only on real iPhone safari) page scrolls to top. I'm trying to prevent scroll on calling click, but no result. 
But if I trying it from desktop, emulate mobile etc. - all works fine.

Could anyone help me with this bag?

Comment: Show the html for the ***button--search*** and show the js for the click handler of the button.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli
html of button is simple - div.button--search{click for search}. It's not important 
$('.button--search').on('click', function() {
    $(body).addClass('header-search').addClass('locked');
    $('#search').focus();
});